# permission denied to source folder by gcc makefile

Tags: static, makefile, static-libraries, wildcard

I have two directories which contains cpp source files (C:\projects\project1\cpputest\src\cpp_sources)
(C:\projects\project1\cpputest\src\cpp_second_sources)

I created two simple makefile within each of the directory where the cpp source files are located. The makefile creates only a static library (windows platform and gnu compiler) "lib.a". For example:

```
#Set this to @ to keep the makefile quiet
ifndef SILENCE
    SILENCE = @
endif

CPPUTEST_HOME = C:/projects/project1/cpputest
CPP    = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall
SOURCE = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS= $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)
TARGET = lib.a

.SUFFIXES: .cpp

all: $(TARGET)

.cpp.o:
    $(CPP) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    ar -rc $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)
```

This works so far. Now I would like to run one makefile from "C:\projects\project1" directory to create one library for the two source directories.I modified the makefile as follow:

```
CPPUTEST_HOME = C:/projects/project1/cpputest
CPP    = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall

SOURCE_DIR = $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/cpp_sources 
SOURCE_DIR += $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/cpp_second_sources

SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS= $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
TARGET = libgcc.a

.SUFFIXES: .cpp

default: $(TARGET)

.cpp.o:
    $(CPP) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

 $(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    ar -rc $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)
```

The output is:

```
g++ -Wall -c C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file1.cpp -o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file1.o
g++ -Wall -c C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file2.cpp -o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file2.o
g++ -Wall -c C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file3.cpp -o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file3.o
g++ -Wall -c C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file4.cpp -o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file4.o
g++ -Wall -c C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file5.cpp -o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file5.o
g++ -Wall -c C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file6.cpp -o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file6.o
g++ -Wall -c C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file7.cpp -o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file7.o
g++ -Wall -c C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file8.cpp -o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file8.o
g++ -Wall -c C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file9.cpp -o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file9.o
g++ -Wall -c C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file10.cpp -o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file10.o
g++ -Wall -c C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file11.cpp -o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file11.o
g++ -Wall -c C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file11.cpp -o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file10.o
g++ -Wall -c C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file12.cpp -o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file12.o
ar -rc libgcc.a C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_second_sources     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file1.o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file2.o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file3.o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file4.o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file5.o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file6.o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file7.o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file8.o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file9.o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file10.o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file11.o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file12.o     C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_sources/file13.o
c:\MinGW\bin\ar.exe: C:/projects/project1/cpputest/cpp_second_sources: Permission denied
make: *** [libgcc.a] Error 1
```

As you can see, all the sources from the directory /cpp_sources are compiled and objects files created, after this, the same has to be done for the directory /cpp_second_sources. Instead of this, the makefile is invoking the ar-rc command on the /cpp_second_sources directory... that's what is strange.

Comment: Always, always use forward slashes and only forward slashes (`/`) as directory separators in GNU make makefiles.  See if that fixes your problem.

Comment: oh, damn, thx! So, now it works partially after changing to forward slashes. The object files are created and after finishing the step "ar -rc $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)" I get the same message as mentioned above

Comment: Please edit your comment and copy/paste the `ar.exe` command line make printed as well as the exact error message.  Without the command line it's hard to know what's wrong.

Comment: @MadScientist: So, make prints this output:'c:\MinGW\bin\ar.exe: C:/projects/project1/cpputest/src/cpp_sources: Permission denied
make: *** [lib.a] Error 1'

Comment: First, please edit your question because it's very hard to read unformatted content in comments.  Second, you are showing me the error message.  What I want to see is the `ar.exe` _command line_, that should be printed _before_ the error message.  There's nothing in your makefile that hides the command line (no `@` prefix to the recipe line) so make should print it out, if your makefile looks like the one above.  If you do have a `@` prefix in your real makefile, remove it.

Comment: @MadScientist I hope my  description below is now better. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha.  This is much more clear.  So your problem is here:

```
SOURCE_DIR = $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/cpp_sources 
SOURCE_DIR += $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/cpp_second_sources

SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/*.cpp)
```

What happens?  Well, you set `SOURCE_DIR` to two different directories, so the value of `SOURCE_DIR` is this:

```
$(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/cpp_sources $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/cpp_second_sources
```

Then you run `$(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/*.cpp)` which expands to a wildcard command like this:

```
$(wildcard $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/cpp_sources $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/cpp_second_sources/*.cpp)
```

Probably you can now see your problem.  You can't just write `$(FOO)/bar` and expect the suffix `/bar` to be appended to each *word* in the expansion of `$(FOO)`; that's not how it works.  It's just added to the end, as written.

If you want the `SOURCE_DIR` variable to be able to hold multiple directories, not just one, then first you should probably rename it to `SOURCE_DIRS` or something more descriptive, and second you have to use things like `addsuffix` etc. to operate on all words in the list:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.cpp,$(SOURCE_DIR))
```

Comment: Yes I see the problem. Now it's Ok and works! Thank you!

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer please accept it (click the check mark) so others know it's already answered.